Surface measure on unit sphere is singular continuous; Folland
Let $\sigma=\sigma_{n-1}$ be the surface measure on the unit sphere $S^{n-1}\subset\mathbb R^n$ and $m$ Lebesgue measure. In Folland's real analysis text, this is defined through $\sigma(E)=n\cdot m(E_1)$, where $E$ is a Borel subset of $S^{n-1}$ and $E_1=\{rx':0<r\leq 1,x'\in E\}$. The author claims (page 106);

The existence of nonzero singular continuous measures in $\mathbb R^n$ is evident enough when $n>1$; the surface measure on the unit sphere discussed in §2.7 is one example.

How can I verify this? A measure $\mu$ is continuous if $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$ and mutually singular with respect to Lebesgue measure $m$ if there exists a Borel set $A$ such that $m(A)=\sigma(A^c)=0$. Together, such a measure is called singular continuous.
I'm very uncertain how to go about this. I don't know if it will follow from later results in the book. For continuity, we want $\{x\}\subset S^{n-1}$, but I'm not sure what $E_1$ then is? A line? If so, it has Lebesgue measure $0$. For the mutual singularity part, I don't know what set to choose such that $m(A)=\sigma(A^c)=0$.

if $x \in S^{n-1}$ then $\sigma {x} = m [0,x] = 0$. For the latter, choose $A=S^{n-1}$.
